# accssesing table with django shell

Tags: python, django

I have a table in `MySQL` named `main_A` with 2 columns.
in my `models.py` I have:

```
from django.db import  models
class main_A(models.Model):
       x= models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
       y= models.IntegerField(blank = True)
```

i want to view it's rows from django shell.
Note: The table **already exists** in the Database.

This is the view of my project files:
http://s18.postimg.org/musyd3pe1/1234.png

I'm statring django with:

```
python manage.py shell
```

now... I'm supposed to write:

```
from models import main_A
```

but says:

> ImportError: NO module named models

i can get pass this error only if I write:

```
from main.models import main_A
```

then I can for example do:

```
p1 = main_A.objects.all()
p1
```

but it tells me:

> table main_main_A doesn't exists

I know that django auto add the name of the package to all tables... and thats why I get `main_main_A` but I don't understand why `from models import main_A` doesn't work.

How do I get pass this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your table in database is named `main_A` then in Django `models.py` you should define the class as `A` not `main_A`:

```
from django.db import  models
class A(models.Model):
       x= models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
       y= models.IntegerField(blank = True)
```

then in Shell:

```
from main.models import A
p1 = A.objects.all()
p1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some keynotes that must be kept in mind, when designing models. Name of table is automatically derived from model metadata.

> Django will define the name of tables as appname_tablename, if not defined explicitly.

For example : Let's my project name is Education, app name is University. I have created a table named student as follows :

```
class Student (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    section = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
```

Django will define it in database as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE university_student (
"id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(30) NOT NULL,
"section" varchar(1) NOT NULL );
```

(Note : An id field is added automatically, you can change this behaviour too)

Now, to give the name of your tables the way you like and not the way Django defines them, you need to use an inner **class Meta** like :

```
class Student (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    section = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Student'
```

Answer (score 1):

Like PyDroid said,
You need to run 2 commands, go to shell, then import your table into shell, then query your data

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py shell
from apps.yourappname import *
Main_A.objects.all().values()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django, you create project and then multiple apps. Each app has its own model. I don't know what is your project structure (project + apps), but I assume that you have your models package present in a separate app. So, whenever you want to access any model, you need to qualify it with the package name. Example, if you have an app say "mysite" with a model say "User", then you have to access user model as

`from mysite.models import User`

then you can use User model.

There might be many apps in a project with its own models, so qualifying "models" with the name of app is must, otherwise Django framework will be confused as to which app's models it should import from.

Answer (score -2):

```
when u created the model in models.py than u need 2 command
    first.
    python manage.py makemigrations
    second.
    python manage.py migrate

    after you get the results empty
    >>> p1 = main_A.objects.all()
    >>> p1
    []
```

Comment: But from what I read... makemigrations and migrate take the model and create the table in the DB... I don't want to create table.. the table alrady exists there, I just want to access it.

Comment: Please, take a look at question update. Your answer is obsolete and can be removed.

Comment: @aayushdagra u must delete the old migrations in migrations folder, do not remove only __pycache__ folder, after u can try again python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate

Comment: I never did migrations at all. I just set up django for existing DB